java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found (app in Android studio)
i am creating an App in which i am using network connection from my android device to my pc xampp server on same wi-fi which will call the php API file. it is throwing the error java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found
I want solution for so that, when user enter the date and hit submit button on android device it sends data from network and access the php API file

Most likely your test server doesn't use a valid TLS certificate. For debugging you can add a test CA to your app: https://developer.android.com/privacy-and-security/security-config#TrustingDebugCa

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
